# Can a lambda function call itself recursively in Python?

Tags: python, recursion, lambda, y-combinator

A regular function can contain a call to itself in its definition, no problem.  I can't figure out how to do it with a lambda function though for the simple reason that the lambda function has no name to refer back to.  Is there a way to do it?  How?

Comment: I'm tempted to tag this what-the-heck or you-dont-want-to-do-this. Why don't you just use a normal function?

Comment: I want to do is to run reduce() on an tree.  The lambda works great on a 1-D list and recursion felt like a natural way to make it work on a tree.  That said, the real reason is that I'm just learning Python, so I'm kicking the tires.

Comment: Reduce works fine with named functions.  Guido wanted to remove lambda expressions from the language for a while.  They survived, but there's still no reason why you _need_ to use them in any situation.

Comment: please don't use reduce. Reduce with a recursive function is crazy complex. It will take forever.  I think it's O(n**3) or something

Comment: @S.Lott bummer.  Is that a problem with the Python interpreter or something more fundamental that I don't understand yet?

Comment: @dsimard: `reduce(f, (a,b,c,d))` is `f(f(f(a, b), c), d)`.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The only way I can think of to do this amounts to giving the function a name:

```
fact = lambda x: 1 if x == 0 else x * fact(x-1)
```

or alternately, for earlier versions of python:

```
fact = lambda x: x == 0 and 1 or x * fact(x-1)
```

**Update**: using the ideas from the other answers, I was able to wedge the factorial function into a single unnamed lambda:

```
>>> map(lambda n: (lambda f, *a: f(f, *a))(lambda rec, n: 1 if n == 0 else n*rec(rec, n-1), n), range(10))
[1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880]
```

So it's possible, but not really recommended!

Comment: `map(lambda n: (lambda f, n: f(f, n))(lambda f, n: n*f(f, n-1) if n > 0 else 1, n), range(10))`

Comment: Useless and fun. That's why I love computing.

Comment: FWIW, here's how to generate numbers in the Fibonacci series with the same technique (assigning it a name): `fibonacci = lambda n: 0 if n == 0 else 1 if n == 1 else fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
`.

Comment: Another way of genreating Fibonacci numbers using lambdas and recusivity:  `f = lambda x: 1 if x in (1,2) else f(x-1)+f(x-2)`

Comment: Can somebody state why doing a recursive anonymous function call is "not recommended"

Comment: Because once your anonymous function is complex enough to need to be recursive, you might as well define it as a function using `def` rather than trying to keep it in a single-line lambda definition.

Comment: I'll add another sticking point to doing this:
>>> fact = lambda x: 1 if x == 0 else x * fact(x-1)
>>> fact_fun = fact
>>> fact = 'Frogs are green'
>>> fact_fun(10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
Which is *really* confusing since the lambda retains the scope from everything created *after it*!

Comment: Perhaps I am 9 years late on this but this has been the final step to proving that my conjecture is correct: every solvable problem can be put into a single python lambda and only said lambda. Useless and fun!

Comment: Argh! Why does python have to have **different** behavior for lambda assignments in comparison to all other assignments!? And who uses recursive lambdas anyways?

Comment: @martineau, doing this poster's wedging on your Fibonacci solution gives: `map(lambda n: (lambda f, *a: f(f, *a))(lambda rec, n: 0 if n == 0 else 1 if n == 1 else rec(rec, n-1) + rec(rec, n-2), n), range(10))`

Answer (score 66):

without reduce, map, named lambdas or python internals:

```
(lambda a:lambda v:a(a,v))(lambda s,x:1 if x==0 else x*s(s,x-1))(10)
```

Comment: Since the first function and its return value are called immediately, they're only serving as assignments. Pythonized a bit, this code says `a = lambda myself, x: 1 if x==0 else x * myself(myself, x-1)` then `v = 10` and finally `a(a, v)`. The complex lambda is designed to accept itself as its first parameter (hence why I've renamed the argument to `myself`), which it uses to call itself recursively

Comment: I posted a new answer leveraging new python syntax `:=` it gives `(f:=lambda x: 1 if x == 0 else x*f(x - 1))(5)` which is shorter and more readable

Answer (score 37):

Contrary to what sth said, you CAN directly do this.

```
(lambda f: (lambda x: f(lambda v: x(x)(v)))(lambda x: f(lambda v: x(x)(v))))(lambda f: (lambda i: 1 if (i == 0) else i * f(i - 1)))(n)
```

The first part is the [fixed-point combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Example_in_Python) *Y* that facilitates recursion in lambda calculus

```
Y = (lambda f: (lambda x: f(lambda v: x(x)(v)))(lambda x: f(lambda v: x(x)(v))))
```

the second part is the factorial function *fact* defined recursively

```
fact = (lambda f: (lambda i: 1 if (i == 0) else i * f(i - 1)))
```

*Y* is applied to *fact* to form another lambda expression

```
F = Y(fact)
```

which is applied to the third part, *n*, which evaulates to the nth factorial

```
>>> n = 5
>>> F(n)
120
```

or equivalently

```
>>> (lambda f: (lambda x: f(lambda v: x(x)(v)))(lambda x: f(lambda v: x(x)(v))))(lambda f: (lambda i: 1 if (i == 0) else i * f(i - 1)))(5)
120
```

If however you prefer *fibs* to *facts* you can do that too using the same combinator

```
>>> (lambda f: (lambda x: f(lambda v: x(x)(v)))(lambda x: f(lambda v: x(x)(v))))(lambda f: (lambda i: f(i - 1) + f(i - 2) if i > 1 else 1))(5)
8
```

Comment: Nice job, you just turned Python into Lisp :)

Comment: I posted a new answer leveraging new python syntax `:=` it gives `(f:=lambda x: 1 if x == 0 else x*f(x - 1))(5)` which is shorter and more readable

Answer (score 23):

You can't directly do it, because it has no name. But with a helper function like the Y-combinator Lemmy pointed to, you can create recursion by passing the function as a parameter to itself (as strange as that sounds):

```
# helper function
def recursive(f, *p, **kw):
   return f(f, *p, **kw)

def fib(n):
   # The rec parameter will be the lambda function itself
   return recursive((lambda rec, n: rec(rec, n-1) + rec(rec, n-2) if n>1 else 1), n)

# using map since we already started to do black functional programming magic
print map(fib, range(10))
```

This prints the first ten Fibonacci numbers: `[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]`,

Comment: I think I finally understand what the Y combinator is for. But I think that in Python it would generally be easier to just use "def" and give the function a name...

Comment: Funny thing is, your Fibonacci example is a great example of something more naturally done with a generator. :-)

Comment: A much better answer than "No".

Comment: +1, that's only answer I can understand, excluding these saying _it's impossible_ and _the function must have name to call herself_.

Comment: Actually you can! I got help and we figured it out! :) See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70714874/how-can-i-get-the-function-object-inside-a-lambda-function

Comment: There are plenty of "poorman's Y" based solutions, in fact.

Answer (score 14):

Yes. I have two ways to do it, and one was already covered. This is my preferred way.

```
(lambda v: (lambda n: n * __import__('types').FunctionType(
        __import__('inspect').stack()[0][0].f_code, 
        dict(__import__=__import__, dict=dict)
    )(n - 1) if n > 1 else 1)(v))(5)
```

Comment: I don't know Python, but that looks terrible. There's really got to be a better way.

Comment: nobody - the point is that this looks horrible for a reason.  Python isn't designed for it, and it's bad practice (in Python).  Lambdas are limited by design.

Comment: Yeah, +1 for the worst Python code ever. When Perl people say "You can write maintainable code in Perl if you know what you are doing", I say "Yeah, and you can write unmaintainable code in Python if you know what you are doing". :-)

Comment: I thought it was impossible to write obfuscated code in python. I have been proven wrong. Thank you my friend

Comment: @habnabit Thanks for the code! If I understood well, this code duplicates the lambda object, from the compiled code. IMHO finding the original object is a "better" way. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70714874/how-can-i-get-the-function-object-inside-a-lambda-function

Answer (score 8):

This answer is pretty basic. It is a little simpler than Hugo Walter's answer:

```
>>> (lambda f: f(f))(lambda f, i=0: (i < 10)and f(f, i + 1)or i)
10
>>>
```

Hugo Walter's answer:

```
(lambda a:lambda v:a(a,v))(lambda s,x:1 if x==0 else x*s(s,x-1))(10)
```

Answer (score 5):

We can now use new python syntax to make it way shorter and easier to read:

Fibonacci:

```py
>>> (f:=lambda x: 1 if x <= 1 else f(x - 1) + f(x - 2))(5)
8
```

Factorial:

```py
>>> (f:=lambda x: 1 if x == 0 else x*f(x - 1))(5)
120
```

We use `:=` to name the lambda: use the name directly in the lambda itself and call it right away as an anonymous function.

(see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572)

Answer (score 4):

```
def recursive(def_fun):
    def wrapper(*p, **kw):
        fi = lambda *p, **kw: def_fun(fi, *p, **kw)
        return def_fun(fi, *p, **kw)

    return wrapper


factorial = recursive(lambda f, n: 1 if n < 2 else n * f(n - 1))
print(factorial(10))

fibonaci = recursive(lambda f, n: f(n - 1) + f(n - 2) if n > 1 else 1)
print(fibonaci(10))
```

Hope it would be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 3):

By the way, instead of slow calculation of Fibonacci:

```
f = lambda x: 1 if x in (1,2) else f(x-1)+f(x-2)
```

I suggest fast calculation of Fibonacci:

```
fib = lambda n, pp=1, pn=1, c=1: pp if c > n else fib(n, pn, pn+pp, c+1)
```

It works really fast.

Also here is factorial calculation:

```
fact = lambda n, p=1, c=1: p if c > n else fact(n, p*c, c+1)
```

Comment: As long as you are speeding it up, don't use recursion at all. Linear recursion is better than a tree, but you'll still overflow the stack with a relatively small argument.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not exactly pure lambda recursion, but it's applicable in places, where you can only use lambdas, e.g. reduce, map and list comprehensions, or other lambdas. The trick is to benefit from list comprehension and Python's name scope. The following example traverses the dictionary by the given chain of keys.

```
>>> data = {'John': {'age': 33}, 'Kate': {'age': 32}}
>>> [fn(data, ['John', 'age']) for fn in [lambda d, keys: None if d is None or type(d) is not dict or len(keys) < 1 or keys[0] not in d else (d[keys[0]] if len(keys) == 1 else fn(d[keys[0]], keys[1:]))]][0]
33
```

The lambda reuses its name defined in the list comprehension expression (fn). The example is rather complicated, but it shows the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer

```
Z = lambda f : (lambda x : f(lambda v : x(x)(v)))(lambda x : f(lambda v : x(x)(v)))

fact = Z(lambda f : lambda n : 1 if n == 0 else n * f(n - 1))

print(fact(5))
```

**Edited: 04/24/2022**

**Explanation**

For this we can use [Fixed-point combinators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator), specifically `Z` combinator, because it will work in strict languages, also called eager languages:

```
const Z = f => (x => f(v => x(x)(v)))(x => f(v => x(x)(v)))
```

Define `fact` function and modify it:

```
1. const fact n = n === 0 ? 1 : n * fact(n - 1)
2. const fact = n => n === 0 ? 1 : n * fact(n - 1)
3. const _fact = (fact => n => n === 0 ? 1 : n * fact(n - 1))
```

Notice that:

> fact === Z(_fact)

And use it:

```js
const Z = f => (x => f(v => x(x)(v)))(x => f(v => x(x)(v)));

const _fact = f => n => n === 0 ? 1 : n * f(n - 1);
const fact = Z(_fact);

console.log(fact(5)); //120
```

See also:
[Fixed-point combinators in JavaScript: Memoizing recursive functions](http://matt.might.net/articles/implementation-of-recursive-fixed-point-y-combinator-in-javascript-for-memoization/)

Comment: The question was about Python.

Comment: @ruohola this is general solution for all languages, but example is written on js

Answer (score 0):

I got some homework about it and figured out something, heres an example of a lambda function with recursive calls:

```
sucesor = lambda n,f,x: (f)(x) if n == 0 else sucesor(n-1,f,(f)(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked motokur's answer as its succint. Here's my thinking about finding the solution :

For recursion, we need to call the same method but since its a lambda, we can't get a ref to it. One way we can reference a name is via method parameters. So, the method we want to call should be passed as a parameter. ( Another way is to get a ref to the current method by inspecting the call stack as in habnabit's answer)

The next thing is to be able to pass different values to each recursive call. So we introduce another parameter to hold the value.

A example calculating the factorial of 6 :

```
(lambda f : f(f,6) )( lambda f, x : 1 if x <= 1 else x * f(f, x-1) )
```

OR

Defining the param from the start instead of hard-coding it :

```
(lambda f,x : f(f,x) )( (lambda f, x : 1 if x <= 1 else x * f(f, x-1)), 6)
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old thread, but it ranks high on some google search results :). With the arrival of python 3.8 you can use the walrus operator to implement a Y-combinator with less syntax!

```py
fib = (lambda f: (rec := lambda args: f(rec, args)))\
      (lambda f, n: n if n <= 1 else f(n-2) + f(n-1))
```

Answer (score -1):

As simple as:

```py
fac = lambda n: 1 if n <= 1 else n*fac(n-1)
```

Answer (score -2):

Lambda can easily replace recursive functions in Python:

For example, this basic compound_interest:

```
def interest(amount, rate, period):
    if period == 0: 
        return amount
    else:
        return interest(amount * rate, rate, period - 1)
```

can be replaced by:

```
lambda_interest = lambda a,r,p: a if p == 0 else lambda_interest(a * r, r, p - 1)
```

or for more visibility :

```
lambda_interest = lambda amount, rate, period: \
amount if period == 0 else \
lambda_interest(amount * rate, rate, period - 1)
```

USAGE:

```
print(interest(10000, 1.1, 3))
print(lambda_interest(10000, 1.1, 3))
```

Output:

```
13310.0
13310.0
```

Answer (score -3):

If you were truly masochistic, you might be able to do it using C extensions, but this exceeds the capability of a lambda (unnamed, anonymous) functon.

No.  (for most values of no).

Comment: ( > this exceeds the capability of a lambda )

---
No, it doesn't. The Y combinator is like the most famous abstract construct there is and it does do that without any hacks.