# recursive lambda-expressions possible?

Tags: python, recursion, lambda

I'm trying to write a lambda-expression that calls itself, but i can't seem to find any syntax for that, or even if it's possible.

Essentially what I wanted to transfer the following function into the following lambda expression: (I realize it's a silly application, it just adds, but I'm exploring what I can do with lambda-expressions in python)

```
def add(a, b):
   if a <= 0:
      return b
   else:
      return 1 + add(a - 1, b)

add = lambda a, b: [1 + add(a-1, b), b][a <= 0]
```

but calling the lambda form of add results in a runtime error because the maximum recursion depth is reached.  Is it even possible to do this in python?  Or am I just making some stupid mistake? Oh, I'm using python3.0, but I don't think that should matter?

Comment: lambda expressions are quite broken in python. i'm not really familiar enough to make a full answer, but if it convinces you, I understand that Guido hates lambda expressions :P

Comment: see here, exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481692/can-a-lambda-function-call-itself-recursively-in-python

Comment: There is nothing broken about them. They are just useless, as you can use a function instead, which is easier to read and understand.

Comment: -1: This is silly.  What's wrong with a def?

Comment: He was pretty clear: learning how lambdas work.  If you're going to -1 questions from people just trying to learn, you've got a lot of downvoting to do.  Learning and experimenting sure is evil!

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: "i can't seem to find any syntax for that" is all the hint someone needs that it's not supported or even sensible.  This isn't an "experiment" it's "I want to do this in spite of obvious language rules preventing it."

Comment: @S.Lott: this isn't silly at all, and it's the foundation of how recursive algorithms are expressed in theoretical computer science.  Now, there's a big difference between practical software engineering and theoretical computer science, but that doesn't mean that one is "sensible" and the other is "silly".

Comment: This question and all its answers are hilarious.

Comment: These concepts are important and sometimes quite practical.  Even fixed-point combinator functions have applications, for example with trampolining.  If you have tail-recursive functions designed to work with the Z combinator, a trampolining substitute can eliminate excessive stack frames without implementation changes.

Answer (score 20):

Maybe you need a Y combinator?

**Edit** - make that a Z combinator (I hadn't realized that Y combinators are more for call-by-name)

Using the definition of the Z combinator from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_combinator)

```
>>> Z = lambda f: (lambda x: f(lambda *args: x(x)(*args)))(lambda x: f(lambda *args: x(x)(*args)))
```

Using this, you can then define add as a completely anonymous function (ie. no reference to its name in its definition)

```
>>> add = Z(lambda f: lambda a, b: b if a <= 0 else 1 + f(a - 1, b))
>>> add(1, 1)
2
>>> add(1, 5)
6
```

Comment: It just needs to be lazy. :-)

Comment: lazy would be **def add(a,b): return a+b** :P

Comment: +1 just for actually using a combinator. Those things are mind-bendingly complex, not to mention rarely used.

Comment: +1 for actually using a combinator that works with python (sorry no Y combinator applicable here, python doesn't do lazy evaluation).

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps you should try the [Z combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_combinator), where this example is from:

```
>>> Z = lambda f: (lambda x: f(lambda *args: x(x)(*args)))(lambda x: f(lambda *args: x(x)(*args)))
>>> fact = lambda f: lambda x: 1 if x == 0 else x * f(x-1)
>>> Z(fact)(5)
120
```

Comment: I just threw up a little in my mouth.

Comment: Either you need to use Haskell instead of Python, or you need to quit using lambda expressions. You're dangerous. :P

Answer (score 6):

First of all recursive lambda expressions are completely unnecessary. As you yourself point out, for the lambda expression to call itself, it needs to have a name. But lambda expressions is nothing else than anonymous functions. So if you give the lambda expression a name, it's no longer a lambda expression, but a function.

Hence, using a lambda expression is useless, and will only confuse people. So create it with a def instead.

But yes, as you yourself discovered, lambda expressions can be recursive. Your own example is. It's in fact so fantastically recursive that you exceed the maximum recursion depth. So it's recursive alright. Your problem is that you always call add in the expression, so the recursion never stops. Don't do that. Your expression can be expressed like this instead:

```
add = lambda a, b: a > 0 and (1 + add(a-1, b)) or b
```

Which takes care of that problem. However, your first def is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Having or not having a name has absolutely nothing to do with whether something is a lambda.  A lambda is a logical *expression* (which happens to have the same interface as a function).  It's perfectly ordinary to give them a name.

Comment: In Python, lambda expression are implemented as anonymous functions. Hence, everything I stated above is correct. What lambdas are in theoretical mathematics is not relevant for this question. Of course it's "ordinary" to give them a name. The point is that in Python you could then just have used a normal function, ans saved yourself the trouble.

Comment: Ah right, so what I did was the "some stupid mistake" option.  I didn't even pause to think that the list would get fully evaluated first.  Thanks for the face palm :)

Comment: I have no interest in theoretical math.  You said that a lambda is an anonymous function, and giving a lambda a name makes it not a lambda.  You're incorrect.  Being anonymous or having a name has exactly nothing to do with whether a Python lambda is a lambda.

Comment: No, I said "lambda expressions are anonymous functions", and in the context of Python (which this is) this is exactly what they are. So if you give it a name, it is, for all intents and purposes, just a normal function. There is no practical or theroretical difference.

Comment: "if you give the lambda expression a name, it's no longer a lambda expression".  It's right there, and it's wrong.  I'm finished discussing this.

Comment: If a lambda is an anonymous function (and it is), what is then a non-anonymous lambda? Right, a function. Again, there is no practical difference between a function and a named lambda. This is a fact.

Answer (score 3):

```
add = lambda a, b: b if a <= 0 else 1 + add(a - 1, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the Y combinator, or some other [fixed point combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_combinator).

Here's an example implementation as a Python lambda expression:

```
Y = lambda g: (lambda f: g(lambda arg: f(f)(arg))) (lambda f: g(lambda arg: f(f)(arg)))
```

Use it like so:

```
factorial = Y(lambda f: (lambda num: num and num * f(num - 1) or 1))
```

That is, you pass into Y() a single-argument function (or lambda), which receives as its argument a recursive version of itself.  So the function doesn't need to know its own name, since it gets a reference to itself instead.

Note that this does get tricky for your add() function because the Y combinator only supports passing a single argument.  You can get more arguments by [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) -- but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.  :-)

Comment: Or just use Z combinator above which supports any number of positional arguments.  You can also support keyword arguments in the same way if desired.

Answer (score 0):

a little late ... but I just found this gem @ http://metapython.blogspot.com/2010/11/recursive-lambda-functions.html

```
def myself (*args, **kw):
    caller_frame = currentframe(1)
    code = caller_frame.f_code
    return  FunctionType(code, caller_frame.f_globals)(*args,**kw)

print "5! = "
print (lambda x:1 if n <= 1 else myself(n-1)*n)(5)
```