# Lambda, calling itself into the lambda definition

Tags: python, functional-programming, lambda

I'm doing a complicated hack in Python, it's a problem when you mix for+lambda+*args (don't do this at home kids), the boring details can be omited, the unique solution I found to resolve the problem is to pass the lambda object into the self lambda in this way:

```
for ...
    lambda x=x, *y: foo(x, y, <selflambda>)
```

It's possible?, thanks a lot.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481692/can-a-lambda-function-call-itself-recursively-in-python

Comment: I saw it, but I do not want to do recursion, and this solutions has a a lot ofuscation to do recursion... Some simplest solution?

Comment: Without the boring details this appears to be little more than a decorator.  Wouldn't that be simpler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While your question is genuinely weird, try something like:

```
>>> import functools
>>> f = lambda selflambda, x=x, *y: foo(x, y, selflambda)
>>> f = functools.partial(f, f)
```

Comment: I'm glad this works for you, but it doesn't do what you asked for. This creates a second function that has a reference to the *first* function, *not* a reference to itself. The two functions behave differently and have different arguments.

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for a [fixed-point combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_combinator), like the Z combinator, for which Wikipedia gives this Python implementation:

```
Z = lambda f: (lambda x: f(lambda *args: x(x)(*args)))(lambda x: f(lambda *args: x(x)(*args)))
```

Z takes one argument, a function describing the function you want, and builds and returns that function.

The function you're looking to build is:

```
Z(lambda f: lambda x=x, *y: foo(x, y, f))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refer to it, you'll have to give it a name

```
bar=lambda x=x, *y: foo(x, y, bar)
```

such is the way of the snake

Comment: This definition grants the power of flowing through the Child-like Empress.  However, be warned, you may only use this with Her permission.  Tu, was du willst.

Comment: This does not work, because the for loop gives unconsistency to the variable naming.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to write a separate function to create the lambda.

```
def mkfun(foo, x):
    f = lambda x=x, *y: foo(x, y, f)
    return f

for ...:
    ...mkfun(foo, x)...
```

This works just like gnibbler's suggestion but can be used in a for loop.

**EDIT:** I wasn't joking. It really works!

```
def foo(x, y, bar):
    print x
    if y:
        bar()  # call the lambda. it should just print x again.

# --- gnibbler's answer
funs = []
for x in range(5):
    bar=lambda x=x, *y: foo(x, y, bar)  # What does bar refer to?
    funs.append(bar)
funs[2](2, True)  # prints 2 4 -- oops! Where did the 4 come from?

# --- this answer
def mkfun(x, foo):
    bar = lambda x=x, *y: foo(x, y, bar)  # different bar variable each time
    return bar
funs = []
for x in range(5):
    funs.append(mkfun(x, foo))
funs[2](2, True)  # prints 2 2
```

Comment: If a lambda is simply an anonymous function, and this technique has to bind it to name, I would think it wouldn't need to use lambda, and is probably harder to read because of it.

Comment: A function with just a lambda operates exacty equal than a lamba, this resolves nothing.

Comment: Yes I try it and much more, finally functools.partial was the solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want to do this with `lambda`.

`lambda`: creates a function object that does not have a name

`def`: creates a function object that does have a name

a name: very useful for calling yourself

```
for ...
    def selflambda(x=x, *y):
        return foo(x, y, selflambda)
    ...
```

Doesn't this do exactly what you requested?  I even called it `selflambda`.  If it doesn't do what you want, would you please explain why it doesn't?

EDIT: Okay, Jason Orendorff has pointed out that this won't work, because each time through the loop, the name `selflambda` will be rebound to a new function, so all the function objects will try to call the newest version of the function.  I'll leave this up for the educational value, not because it is a good answer.

Comment: steveha: Look closely. What does the `selflambda` in that function refer to after the next loop iteration?

Comment: Hmmm.  Okay, so that is why the answer he accepted involves `functional.partial()`.  I'll update my answer.