# Python lambda function to calculate factorial of a number

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda

I have just started learning python. I came across lambda functions. On one of the problems, the author asked to write a one liner lambda function for factorial of a number.

This is the solution that was given:

```
num = 5
print (lambda b: (lambda a, b: a(a, b))(lambda a, b: b*a(a, b-1) if b > 0 else 1,b))(num)
```

I cannot understand the weird syntax. What does a(a,b) mean?

Can someone explain?

Thanks

Comment: I got a better one: `lambda b: math.factorial(b)`

Comment: Dont reinvent the square-shaped wheel.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The factorial itself is almost as you'd expect it. You infer that the `a` is... the factorial function. `b` is the actual parameter.

```
<factorial> = lambda a, b: b*a(a, b-1) if b > 0 else 1
```

This bit is the application of the factorial:

```
<factorial-application> = (lambda a, b: a(a, b))(<factorial>, b)
```

`a` is the factorial function itself. It takes itself as its first argument, and the evaluation point as the second. This can be generalized to `recursive_lambda` as long as you don't mind `a(a, b - 1)` instead of `a(b - 1)`:

```
recursive_lambda = (lambda func: lambda *args: func(func, *args))
print(recursive_lambda(lambda self, x: x * self(self, x - 1) if x > 0 else 1)(6))
# Or, using the function verbatim:
print(recursive_lambda(lambda a, b: b*a(a, b-1) if b > 0 else 1)(6))
```

So we have the outer part:

```
(lambda b: <factorial-application>)(num)
```

As you see all the caller has to pass is the evaluation point.

---

If you *actually* wanted to have a recursive lambda, you could just [name the lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481692/can-a-lambda-function-call-itself-recursively-in-python):

```
fact = lambda x: 1 if x == 0 else x * fact(x-1)
```

If not, you can use [a simple helper function](http://ideone.com/wPq1BH). You'll notice that `ret` is a lambda that can refer to itself, unlike in the previous code where no lambda could refer to itself.

```
def recursive_lambda(func):
    def ret(*args):
        return func(ret, *args)
    return ret

print(recursive_lambda(lambda factorial, x: x * factorial(x - 1) if x > 1 else 1)(6))  # 720
```

Both ways you don't have to resort to ridiculous means of passing the lambda to itself.

Comment: To clarify: `a` is being passed to itself?

Comment: That is a whole new level of twisted.

Comment: Sorry, for replying after so long. I understood what you explained. I almost forgot that I didn't post back.

Answer (score 7):

It is this simple:

```
n=input()

print reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,range(1,n+1))
```

Answer (score 6):

Let's peel this one liner open like an onion.

```
print (lambda b: (Y))(num)
```

We are making an anonymous function (the keyword lambda means we're about to type a series of parameter names, then a colon, then a function that uses those parameters) and then pass it num to satisfy its one parameter.

```
   (lambda a, b: a(a, b))(X,b)
```

Inside of the lambda, we define another lambda. Call this lambda Y. This one takes two parameters, a and b. a is called with a and b, so a is a callable that takes itself and one other parameter

```
            (lambda a, b: b*a(a, b-1) if b > 0 else 1
            ,
            b)
```

These are the parameters to Y. The first one is a lambda function, call it X. We can see that X is the factorial function, and that the second parameter will become its number.

That is, if we go up and look at Y, we can see that we will call:

```
X(X, b)
```

which will do

```
b*X(X, b-1) if b > 0 else 1
```

and call itself, forming the recursive part of factorial.

And looking all the way back outside, we can see that b is num that we passed into the outermost lambda.

```
num*X(X, b-1) if num > 0 else 1
```

This is kind of confusing because it was written as a confusing one liner :)

Comment: It was an online competition on one liners. And I was preparing for that. It was confusing but after spending a great amount of time, I think I got it down. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are two hard parts about this function.
1. `lambda a, b: b*a(a, b-1) if b > 0 else 1`.
2. the "b" that's folowing 1.

For 1, it's nothing more than:

```
def f(a, b):
    if b > 0:
        b * a(a, b - 1)
    else:
        1
```

For 2, this b

```
(lambda b: (lambda a, b: a(a, b))(lambda a, b: b*a(a, b-1) if b > 0 else 1,b))(num)
                                                                      (this one)
```

is actually this b:

```
(lambda b: (lambda a, b: a(a, b))(lambda a, b: b*a(a, b-1) if b > 0 else 1,b))(num)
   (this one)
```

The reason is that it's not inside the definition of the second and third lambda, so it refers to the first b.

After we apply num and strip off the outer function:

```
(lambda a, b: a(a, b))  (lambda a, b: b*a(a, b-1) if b > 0 else 1, num)
```

It's just applying a function to a tuple,  (lambda a, b: b*a(a, b-1) if b > 0 else 1, num)
Let's call this tuple as (f, num)  (f's def is above)
Applying `lambda a, b: a(a, b)` on it, we get

f(f, num).

Suppose your num is 5.
By definiton of f, it first evaluates to

```
5 * f(f, 4)
```

Then to:

```
5 * (4 * f(f, 3))
```

All the way down to

```
5 * (4 * (3 * (2 * (1 * f(f, 0)))))
```

f(f, 0) goes to 1.

```
5 * (4 * (3 * (2 * (1 * 1))))
```

Here we go, the factorial of 5.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the below lambda expression

```
     fact = lambda n:1 if n==0 else n*fact(n-1)
     print(fact(5)
     >>> 120
```

Answer (score 0):

the generalized def of recursive lambda is as below

```
recursive_lambda = (lambda func: lambda *args: func(func, *args))
```

Answer (score 0):

Very nicely explained! Only one minor fix: if b > 1 NOT if b > 0

The result is the same but logically more correct as it is executing one unnecessary additional loop (even though multiplying by 1)

Wikipedia => n!, is the product of all positive integers less than or equal to n

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do a factorial using lambda expression then you need to put if else condition like:

```
if x==1: 
    return 1 
else 
    return x*function_name(x-1)
```

for example `fact` is my lambda expression:

`fact( lambda x:1 if x==1/else x*fact(x-1) )`

## this is recursive if else condition

Answer (score 0):

**Easy Method to find Factorial using Lambda Function**

```
fac = lambda x : x * fac(x-1) if x > 0 else 1

print(fac(5))
```

output:
120

**User Input to find Factorial**

```
def fac():

    fac_num = int(input("Enter Number to find Factorial "))

    factorial = lambda f : f * factorial(f-1) if f > 0 else 1

    print(factorial(fac_num))

fac()
```

Enter Number to find Factorial : 5

120

Answer (score 0):

The code in question:

```
lambda b : (lambda a, b : a(a, b)) (lambda a, b : b * a(a, b-1) if b > 0 else 1,  b)
```

To make it clearer, let me `replace variable names a with f, and b with n`.

```
lambda n : (lambda f, n : f(f, n)) (lambda f, n : n * f(f, n-1) if n > 0 else 1,  n)
```

Recursive Factorial is a function that will call itself, or be applied to itself, something like f(f).
Let us set `Factorial(n) to be f(f,n)` and compute as follows:

```
def func(f, n):  # takes a function and a number, return a number.
        if n > 0 :
            return n * f(f, n-1)
        else :
            return 1
```

Translating the above def func into lambda notation:

```
func is     lambda f, n : n * f(f, n-1) if n > 0 else 1
```

func is then to be applied to itself along with integer n.

Back to beginning statement, `Factorial(n) is f(f,n), or f(func,n) when func is applied into f.`

```
def Factorial(n):  
    # return f (func, n)  # next, substitute f and func with their corresponding lambdas.
    return (lambda f, n : f(f, n))  (lambda f, n : n * f(f, n-1) if n > 0 else 1, n)
```

and using lambda instead of def Factorial, the whole thing becomes:

```
lambda n : (lambda f, n : f(f, n)) (lambda f, n : n * f(f, n-1) if n > 0 else 1, n)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
while True: 
    #It is this simple:
    from functools import reduce
    n=input('>>')
    n=int(n)
    if n==0:
        print('factorial: ',1)
    elif n<0:
        print('invalid input')
    else:
        print('factorial: ',(reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,list(range(1,n+1)))))
```

Comment: The question was about understanding a complex expression, not about coming up with a new one. Also, you are using an imported function `reduce`, which was,implicitly, not allowed.

Comment: Another thing - an `import` statement inside a loop - definitely a bad idea.