# How to write a lambda function that performs a function on the integers from one to n where n is an integer?

Tags: python

Write a lambda function called factorials_1_to_n that computes the factorials of the numbers from 1 to n. Hint: Use the function factorial you already created.

The only thing I can think of doing is writing a for loop within the lambda function like.... for i in range(1,len(n)+1): factorial(i)…. but for loops are not allowed within a lambda function.

```
def factorial(n):
product=n
while n!=1:
    product=product*(n-1)
    n=n-1
return(product)
y=factorial(4)
print(y)


factorials_1_to_n = lambda n: ????????
y=factorials_1_to_n(4)
print(y)
```

Comment: The whole *point* of a `lambda` is to not need a name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15401376/python-lambda-function-to-calculate-factorial-of-a-number

Answer (score 0):

I assume that a list is an acceptable result type

`factorials_1_to_n = lambda n: [factorial(i+1) for i in range(n)]`

The `i+1` is used to calculate it from 1 to n, instead of from 0 to n-1.

See [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in python