# Python sum and then multiply values of several lists

Tags: python

Is there way to write following code  in one line?

```
my_list = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3]]
result = 1
for l in list:
    result = result * sum(l)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `reduce` on the *summed* sublists gotten from `map`.

This does it:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, map(sum, my_list))
36
```

---

In python 2.x, the `import` will not be needed as `reduce` is a builtin:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, map(sum, my_list))
36
```

Comment: Wouldn't it also work without the import? At least for me it does.

Comment: @Ohumeronen not in Python 3.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
import operator
my_list = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3]]
print reduce(operator.mul, [sum(l) for l in my_list])
```

Comment: Thanks for interesting suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

with `numpy`

```
In [1]: from numpy import prod
In [2]: prod([sum(i) for i in my_list])
Out[2]: 36
```

Another method.

```
In [1]: eval('*'.join(str(item) for item in [sum(i) for i in my_list]))
Out[1]: 36
```

Comment: @micgeronimo It's also another attempt. And i showed another method also.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are some people out there who think that a one-liner which requires an `import` statement is not a true one-liner. Just for fun, those who think so might prefer this admittedly obfuscated solution to the approaches suggested so far:

```
In [389]: (lambda f: lambda n: f(f, n))(lambda rec, x: 1 if not x else x[0]*rec(rec, x[1:]))(map(sum, my_list))
Out[389]: 36
```

The code above relies on the built-in functions `map()` and `sum()` to compute the sums of the sublists, and on [recursive calls to a `lambda` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481692/can-a-lambda-function-call-itself-recursively-in-python) to compute the product of the sums.