# Can looping be done in a lambda?

Tags: python, loops, lambda

I tried looping in a lambda function, and my code is:

```
zxm=lambda k:[k+x for x in range(k)]
print(zxm(5))
```

and the output which I got is when I gave the input:

```
[5,6,7,8,9]
```

My expected output is however the sum of all the 5 numbers and I want:

```
35
```

How can we loop in lambda? Also, is there a chance of recursion in one?

Answer (score 7):

That's not a loop per se, it's a list comprehension. You can use `sum` to get the sum, for example.

```
In [7]: zxm = lambda k: sum(k+x for x in range(k))

In [8]: zxm(5)
Out[8]: 35
```

Note that statements like `for` are forbidden inside `lambda`; only expressions are permitted, so while you can use list comprehensions you cannot write a traditional `for` loop.

Comment: Note that this solution used a generator comprehension (`()`) rather than a list comprehension (`[]`) which can be more efficient (especially if the list is big). More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension

Answer (score 1):

First, there is `sum` method in python. You can just do `sum(zxm(5))`. Recursive lambdas do exists (see: [Y Combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Fixed_point_combinators_in_lambda_calculus)), and this is possible in python (see [Can a lambda function call itself recursively in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481692/can-a-lambda-function-call-itself-recursively-in-python)), however, the practicality of this is not particularly strong. Lambdas can be looped (over lists) inside of as you have done here. The issue is not that `zxm` is a lambda but the way it is defined. You can get the sum in `zxm` by defining it as such `zxm=lambda k: sum([k+x for x in range(k)])`.