# Using lambda functions to sum digits and count digits

Tags: python, recursion, lambda, python-2.x, ternary-operator

How can I convert these two functions to use lambda notation?

```
def sum_digits(number):
    if number == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return (number % 10) + sum_digits(number / 10)

def count_digit(number):
    if number == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 + count_digit(number/10)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a lambda function call itself recursively in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481692/can-a-lambda-function-call-itself-recursively-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sum_digits = lambda number: 0 if number == 0 else (number % 10) + sum_digits (number / 10)

count_digit = lambda number: 0 if number == 0 else 1 + count_digit(number/10)
```

Incidentally, this is a *bad* time to use lambdas, since you need the function names in order for them to call themselves. The point of lambdas is that they're anonymous.

Comment: i thought i was wrong if i did that but it's just someone asking for this alternative method since i converted those two functions into an HOF already

Comment: Do you mean that you want a non-recursive form of each function?

Comment: No, I purposely wrote them recursively. I just wanted to know how i could replace the function itself by using a lambda notation instead. My HOF does this: digits(number,term). Now I can replace term with the lambda function.

Comment: A perk of Python is that you don't even need to write them as lambdas to do that. Pass in the function as an argument. If I'm understanding your intent, you can call `digits(number, sum_digits)` even when it's not a lambda.

Comment: I know, but I have never been good with lambda because I don't see the use of it most of the time. It was specifically required as an comment in my overall program.

Answer (score 5):

A string-oriented approach wouldn't require recursion:

```
sum_of_digits = lambda n: sum(int(d) for d in str(n))
count_digit = lambda n: len(str(n))
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-308.html) for the body of the lambda:

```
>>> sum_digits = lambda n: 0 if n == 0 else (n % 10) + sum_digits(n // 10)
>>> count_digit = lambda n: 0 if n == 0 else 1 + count_digit(n // 10)
```

Also, if is preferred to use `//` for the division so that the code will still work in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum_digits = lambda number: 0 if number == 0 else (number % 10) + sum_digits (number//10)
count_digit = lambda number: 0 if number == 0 else 1 + count_digit(number//10)
print(sum_digits(2546))
print(count_digit(2546))
```

Will work on python 3 too...

Answer (score 0):

```
print(list(map(lambda x: sum(int(i) for i in str(x)),list(map(int,input().split())))))
```

this might be useful for reading and using lamda function on the same line.