# Recursive one liner function to print numbers from N to 1

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def recur(n):
    print(n)
    if n>1:
        recur(n-1)
```

How can this be converted to just line. I can not find a way to use the logic as 
`recur = lambda x: print(x) if.......`

I can not even use

```
func = lambda x: [print(i) for i in range(x,0,-1)]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a lambda function call itself recursively in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481692/can-a-lambda-function-call-itself-recursively-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the numbers printed on the same line, you can use the `end=` parameter of the print function:

```
printDown = lambda n: print(n,end=" ") or printDown(n-1) if n>1 else print(n)

printDown(10)

10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

If you want them on separate lines:

```
printDown = lambda n: print(n) or (printDown(n-1) if n>1 else None)

printDown(10)

10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible recursive lambda:

```
recur = lambda n: [print(n), recur if n>1 else lambda x: None][1](n-1)

recur(10)
```

Prints:

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python >= 3.8, you can do it in one line entirely:

```
print(*(x := lambda n: [n]+x(n-1) if n else [])(10), sep='\n')
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Note that this also does not abuse a comprehension or expression for side effects. `x` can still be used to create a common list now:

```
x(5)
# [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```