# How i can change function to one line in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, filter, tree

```
def height (t):
  if not t:
    return 0                                   # (1)
  elif not t.nodes:
    return 1                                   # (2)
  else:
    return 1 + max(height(n) for n in t.nodes) # (3)
```

hello guys some one can help me and change this function to pipline?
using map , filter , lambda

you don't need to write def height
you need to use only with lambda map filter (PIPLINE)

Comment: Why? Single-line does not equal better, faster or more readable code

Comment: i know but this is my mission..

Comment: Is a single line if acceptable?

Comment: Is `not t` a euphemism for `t is None`, so that future uses of `t.nodes` don't raise an `AttributeError`?

Comment: yes i need only one line and there be a recursion as well

Comment: What do you mean by "pipline"? Why do you expect the use of "map , filter , lambda" – these do not naturally translate to the operations shown in the original code.

Comment: Solution based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8703135/984421): `(lambda h: lambda t: h(h, t))(lambda h, t: 0 if not t else 1 if not t.nodes else 1 + max(h(h, n) for n in t.nodes))(t)`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only return 0 if `not t`, and for other cases you return 1, you could go with this simple line:

```
return 0 if not t else 1 if not t.nodes else 1 + max(height(n) for n in t.nodes)
```

Comment: but i need to Recursion

Comment: @GalBirka but i ask for not def you can do it in pipline?